# Angular function is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

In my web application I want to verify if the user has the permissions to continue.

This is the .run method in my index.js file:

```
  .run(function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, $window) {
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, $window) {
  if (Auth.isLoggedIn && $window.localStorage.identityToken) {

    var requiredAdmin = toState.data.requiredAdmin; 
    if (requiredAdmin && $window.localStorage.isAdmin){
      $state.go(toState.name);
    } else {
      $state.go(fromState.name);
    }
    var shouldGoToMain = fromState.name === 'login' && toState.name !== 'app.dashboard' ;

    if (shouldGoToMain){
      $state.go('app.dashboard');
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $state.go(toState.name);
    }
    return;
  } else { 
    $state.go('login');
    return;
  }

  // unmanaged
});
```

});

The console error is: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:strictdi] function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, $window) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You enabled [strict mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp), in order to detect where you forgot to use $inject or the array notation to make sure your code can be safely minified.

The message tells you that you failed to properly annotate your injectable functions. Note that, in addition to that, your code doesn't make much sense:

- the function passed to run() is supposed to take injectable services as argument, and all its arguments except $window are not services.
- the function passed to $on() is not an injectable function. So passing it $windows makes no sense. The router will only invoke it with the 4 first arguments.

So, your code should be:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$window', function($rootScope, $window) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
```

I would strongly advise to stop annotating your injectable functions by hand, and to use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to do that for you.

Comment: It works but console gives me this error: $state.go is not a function. Why? (I've also added two dependences on you code:   .run(['$rootScope', '$window', function($rootScope, $window) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, Auth, $state)  )

Comment: You're doing the exact same mistake again. The method passed to $on is NOT an injectable function. Passing Auth and $state to that function makes no sense at all. These services should be injected into the function passed to run() (and their name should thus also be added to the array)

Comment: Done! But I have a strange local error... when it goes to else { $state.go('login'); }  it returns to if (Auth.isLoggedIn && $window.localStorage.identityToken), then goes to $state.go('login') and turn back into if (Auth....) and continues untile browser crash... If you want, I pushed all the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677234/statechange-causes-inspected-target-crash-in-angular

Comment: Well, that's quite expected: you want this code to be executed each time the router goes to a state. And at the end, you tell the router to go to the 'login' state. You should not execute the `else` block if the requested state is 'login'.

Comment: I have the same problem inside the 'if' block... $state.go('app.dashboard'), $state.go(fromState.name), etc... I just want to do a code which check if the user has the permissions... then, if he has them, let continue him..

Comment: If you want to let the user continue, don't do $state.go(...). Just don't do anything.

Comment: Yes I thought about it, but I also have the opposite case: 'if the user does not have permission, remains', then: $ state.go (fromState.name). How do I say 'stay' in the current position?