# Error: [$injector:strictdi] is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode

Tags: angularjs

After upgrade to angular-ui-router 1.0.5 (from 1.0.0) I get the following:

```
Error: [$injector:strictdi] function(searchScope) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
```

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/strictdi?p0=function(searchScope)

I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677538/angular-function-is-not-using-explicit-annotation-and-cannot-be-invoked-in-stric) that this means I

> enabled strict mode, in order to detect where you forgot to use $inject or the array notation to make sure your code can be safely
>   minified.

How is this supposed to help me finding the Error? Is it in the Defintion  `searchScope` or is the `searchScope` itself wrongly injected somewhere? How can I find where?

It's definition is

```
.factory('searchScope', ['$location', '$rootScope', 'Query', '$http', '$stateParams', 'language', '$state',
function($location, $rootScope, Query, $http, $stateParams, language, $state) {
```

(angular 1.6.5)

Any suggestions?

*edit*

SearchScope is a service I use in a lot of services and directives. I checked all components using it and all their definitions looked like

```
.directive('foodirective', ['searchScope', function (searchScope) {
```

which seem pretty correct to me...

Comment: do you mean to 1.6.5?\

Comment: did you add `'use strict';` in the beginning of file?

Comment: Maybe one of your injected services aren't using $inject or the array notation.

Comment: There's no such thing as searchScope in UI Router, so it's not clear how the problem is related to it. The problem is in some function that injects searchScope. Just search for it in your code base. You're the only person who can do this.

Comment: Yes, sry 1.6.5.

Comment: Yes I use 'use strict'; and this should be so.

Comment: No, I know,  searchScope is a service I wrote. My question was, what kind of stuff I should search for - a error in searchScope itself or a place where it gets injected or what else. Your answer @estus therefore suggest the second, so I will check every service's definition.

Comment: By the way I don't have any clue how the problem is related to ui-router, it just appaered the since the update of ui-router, that's all I know.

Comment: This probably means that a function that injects searchScope is called in some route controller or resolver that weren't called before for some reason.

Comment: I checked every component which uses searchScope, and all their definitions looked like `.directive('arScopedHref', ['searchScope', function (searchScope) {`, wich seems correct to me... whatelse may I look for?

Comment: OK I finally found it, it was in a resolver. If you want to formulate a answer estus, I mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since original commenter never claimed his points here is the correct Answer by @[Estus Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask):

> This probably means that a function that injects searchScope is called in some route controller or resolver that weren't called before for some reason.

That helped me to find the source of the error very soon.